# Can we find relation/function between two vertical edge in Vertical Edge Detected Image?

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am doing image processing. I am trying to optimally classify images based on a mathematical calculation.

I don't know how to find the relation between two vertical edges in an image. How can this be done?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What relationship do you want to find? The angle between them, their relative lengths? The distance between them? Adding a sample image would help.

Comment: Welcome to SO; your question is way too broad & vague, please do take some time to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: I tried to make your question more readable by making sentences shorter and splitting into two paragraphs. But you should really add the relevant Python code to your question and show where you have a problem in that code.

Comment: You’ve fixed a grammar mistake in your question, but you haven’t addressed the questions asked of you in the comments. You are not getting an answer because people don’t know what you are asking. Please clarify what type of relation you are looking for. What does “the relation between two vertical edges” mean to you? Spell it out in a different way, using different words, so that people can understand what you are thinking of.